# Insertion sort with a linked list, "Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference" - Fortran

Tags: linked-list, segmentation-fault, fortran, selection-sort

I am trying to use a linked list to do selection sort. However, I receive a segmentation fault.

"""

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:  
\#0  0x7f191e86a32a   
\#1  0x7f191e869503   
\#2  0x7f191e49cf1f  
\#3  0x7f191e9e9330  
\#4  0x7f191e9ed0b4  
\#5  0x7f191e9e423c  
\#6  0x7f191e9e46dc  
\#7  0x55ed5c77be79  
\#8  0x55ed5c77bfa6  
\#9  0x7f191e47fb96  
\#10  0x55ed5c77b9c9  
\#11  0xffffffffffffffff  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

"""

I'm convinced it is caused when I try and write out the data in between my "output" do loop. I find it quite dificult to see how I screw up with the memory.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

```
program insertion_sort
implicit none

! Derived data type to store integer values in 
type int_value
  integer                   :: value
  type (int_value), pointer :: next_value
end type

! Data dictionary: declare variable types & definitions
type (int_value), pointer :: head       ! Pointer to head of list
character(20)             :: filename   ! input data file name
integer                   :: istat      ! status: 0 for succes
integer                   :: nvals = 0  ! Number of data read
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr        ! Ptr to new value
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr1       ! Temp ptr for search
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr2       ! Temp ptr for search
type (int_value), pointer :: tail       ! Pointer to tail of list
integer                   :: temp       ! Temporary variable

! Get the name of the file containing the input data
write (*,*) 'Enter the file name with the data to be sorted'
read (*,'(A20)') filename

! Open input data file
Open (Unit=9, file=filename, status='OLD', action='read', &
      iostat=istat )

! Was the open succesful
fileopen: if ( istat == 0 ) then              ! Open succesful

  ! The file was opened succesfully, so read the data value 
  ! to sort, allocate a variable for it, and locate the proper
  ! point to insert the new value into the list

  input: do
    read (9, *, iostat=istat) temp            ! Get value
    if ( istat /=0 ) exit                     ! Exit on end of data
    nvals = nvals + 1                         ! Bump count

    allocate (ptr, STAT=istat)                ! Get value
    ptr%value = temp                          ! Store number

    ! Now find out where to put it in the list.
    new: if (.not. associated(head)) then     ! No values in list
      head => ptr                             ! Place at front
      tail => head                            ! Tail pts to new value
      nullify (ptr%next_value)                ! nullify next ptr
    else
      ! Values alreadd in list. Check for location.
      front: if ( ptr%value < head%value ) then
        ! Add at front of list
        ptr%next_value => head
        head => ptr
      else if ( ptr%value >= tail%value ) then
        ! Add at end of list
        tail%next_value => ptr
        tail => ptr
        nullify (tail%next_value)
      else
        ! Find place to add value
        ptr1 => head
        ptr2 => ptr1%next_value
        search: do
          if ( (ptr%value >= ptr1%value) .and. & 
              (ptr%value < ptr2%value) ) then
          ! Insert value here
          ptr%next_value => ptr2
          ptr1%next_value = ptr
          exit search
          end if
          ptr1 => ptr2
          ptr2 => ptr2%next_value
        end do search
      end if front
    end if new
  end do input

  ! WHERE I BELIEVE THE SEGMENTATION FAULT OCCURS
  ! Now write out the data. 
  ptr => head
  output: do
    if ( .not. associated(ptr) ) exit            ! Pointer valid?
    write (*, '(I10)')  ptr%value                ! Yes: Write value
    ptr => ptr%next_value                        ! Get next pointer
    deallocate(ptr, StAT=istat)
  end do output

else fileopen
  ! Else file open failed. Tell user.
  write (*, '(A,I6)') 'File open failed--status =', istat

end if fileopen

end program insertion_sort
```

Comment: Please recompile with -g to get debug information so a more sensible backtrace will be shown.

Comment: Whenever yo have these kinds of problems, use all debugging flags your compiler has. For example `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all` or `ifort -g -warn -check`. These kinds of codes with pointers are notoriously difficult to reason about and debug must usually be done with a debugger and similar tools (e.g. valgrind). One cannot just look at a backtrace and see the error.

Comment: Why are you deallocating the `PTR` after you have done a pointer assignment?  That is, `ptr => ptr%next_value ; deallocate(ptr, StAT=istat)` cannot be what you want to do.

Comment: A pointer in Fortran can be associated, unassociated, or undefined.  You cannot use `ASSOCIATED` with an undefined pointer.  What is the initial status of your `head` variable?

Comment: This line also does not do what you want `ptr1%next_value = ptr`.  There is a difference between ordinary assignment and pointer assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up. I have finished the code and it works now. The segmentation fault was avoided by nullifying the head pointer in the beginning. The previous code also had issues in its if statements, as it before did not account for the last or first number being either highest or lowest.

```
program insertion_sort
implicit none

! Derived data type to store integer values in 
type int_value
  real                      :: value
  type (int_value), pointer :: p
end type

! Data dictionary: declare variable types & definitions
type (int_value), pointer :: head => null()    ! Pointer to head of list
character(20)             :: filename          ! input data file name
integer                   :: istat             ! status: 0 for succes
integer                   :: nvals = 0, i = 0  ! Number of data read
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr               ! Ptr to new value
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr1              ! Temp ptr for search
type (int_value), pointer :: ptr2              ! Temp ptr for search
type (int_value), pointer :: tail              ! Pointer to tail of list
real                      :: temp              ! Temporary variable
character(80)             :: msg               ! I/O Message

! Get the name of the file containing the input data
write (*,*) 'Enter the file name with the data to be sorted'
read (*,'(A20)') filename

! Open input data file
Open (Unit=9, file=filename, status='OLD', action='read', &
      iostat=istat, iomsg=msg )

! Was the open succesful
fileopen: if ( istat == 0 ) then              ! Open succesful

  ! The file was opened succesfully, so read the data value 
  ! to sort, allocate a variable for it, and locate the proper
  ! point to insert the new value into the list

  input: do
    read (9, *, iostat=istat) temp            ! Get value
    if ( istat /=0 ) exit                     ! Exit on end of data
    nvals = nvals + 1                         ! Bump count

    allocate (ptr, STAT=istat)                ! Get value
    ptr%value = temp                          ! Store number

    ! Now find out where to put it in the list.
    new: if (.not. associated(head)) then     ! No values in list
      head => ptr                             ! Place at front
      tail => head                            ! Tail pts to new value
      nullify (ptr%p)                         ! nullify next ptr
    else
      ! Values alreadd in list. Check for location.
      front: if ( ptr%value <= head%value ) then
        ! Add at front of list
        ptr%p => head
        head => ptr
      else if ( ptr%value >= tail%value ) then
        ! Add at end of list
        tail%p => ptr
        tail => ptr
        nullify (tail%p)

      else
        ! Find place to add value
        ptr1 => head
        ptr2 => ptr1%p
        search: do
          if ( (ptr%value >= ptr1%value) .and. &
              (ptr%value <= ptr2%value) ) then
          ! Insert value here
          ptr%p => ptr2
          ptr1%p = ptr
          exit search
          end if
          ptr1 => ptr2
          ptr2 => ptr2%p
        end do search
      end if front
    end if new
  end do input

   !Now write out the data.
  ptr => head
  output: do
    if ( .not. associated(ptr) ) exit            ! Pointer valid?
    write (*, '(F10.4)')  ptr%value              ! Yes: Write value
    ptr => ptr%p                                 ! Get next pointer
  end do output

  deallocate(ptr,STAT=istat)

else fileopen
  ! Else file open failed. Tell user.
  write (*, '(A,I6)') 'File open failed--status =', istat

end if fileopen

end program insertion_sort
```

Comment: I *strongly* suggest default-nullifying all pointer components in your derived types. Like `type (int_value), pointer :: p => null()`